# Submit form onchange of dropdown when javascript is disable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using jquery ajax function for loading content of a dropdown on change of another dropdown this works fine, Now when i disable javascript i want my form to submit on change of that dropdown so i can load that content in another dropdown after post back because that ajax function wouldnt work how i can do this. I am using Asp.Net MVC 2 and jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `onChange` when javascript is disabled - it's a javascript function.

The think you could do is to put a submit button in the form and when the javascript is enabled - hide it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without javascript. You can put a refresh button near the dropdown and hide it when javascript is enabled. On the button's click event you can populate your dropdown.